# Select values within a range around average

Tags: sql

I am wanting to find the average price from a range of objects, then to select objects that fall within a tolerance of that average range such as
supplies table.

```
food       price
-------------
'fish'     $1
'bread'    $2
'eggs'     $3
'coffee'   $4
'bananas'  $5
```

The average price here is $3. How do I e.g.

```
SELECT food FROM SUPPLIES 
WHERE food BETWEEN AVG(PRICE)-$1 AND AVG(PRICE)+$1
```

Most of the variations I have tried on the formula states invalid use of group function. I have also replaced 'WHERE' with 'HAVING' with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to use `Aggregate` function in `WHERE` clause. So you have to use `Sub query` to get the average price. I have assumed Price stored as `decimal` in you DB. Try something like this,

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(food VARCHAR(20), price DECIMAL(18,2))

INSERT INTO @table 

select 'fish', 1 union
select 'bread',    2 union
select 'eggs',     3 union
select 'coffee',   4 union
select 'bananas',  5

SELECT food FROM @table 
WHERE price BETWEEN
(
    SELECT  AVG(PRICE)-1 FROM @table
)
AND
(
    SELECT  AVG(PRICE)+1 FROM @table  
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fantastic. Easy answer. Looking over all my attempts, I came very close to this. I just missed the last SELECT statement. Thank you